# Concordance correlation coefficient for negative correaltion

Tags: python, statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation

A question regarding the [Concordance correlation coefficient (CCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient).
I would like to implement it in Python. Following the Wikipedia entry, one of the possible implementations would be

```py
import numpy as np
def ccc(x,y):
    vx, cov_xy, cov_xy, vy = np.cov(x,y, bias=True).flat
    mx, my = x.mean(), y.mean()
    return 2*cov_xy / (vx + vy + (mx-my)**2)
```

However, I have noticed that it does not behave as expected when it comes to negative correlations:

```py
>>> x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> y = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> ccc(x,y)
1.0
>>> ccc(x,-y)
-0.16923076923076918
```

From my understanding, the CCC should be able to capture negative correlation just as well as the Pearson's r, in which case I would expect `ccc(x,-y) == -1`.

Could anyone point me to the reason I am not getting the expected value here? Is there something wrong with my implementation, or is the CCC indeed not capable of capturing such cases?

Comment: I found a document titled "The Pearson Correlation Coefficient (r) vs. Lin’s Concordance Coefficient (rc) ". It might be helpful. https://academic.csuohio.edu/kneuendorf/c63310/CorrsCompared10.pdf